# How to get custom error from dio in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am trying to get the custom error coming from the backend but DIO gives me this error instead:

> DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [400]

Here's my code:

```
  @override
  Future<SignUpResponseModel> registerBuyer(BuyerModel user) async {
    final response = await api.dio.post('api/users/buyer', data: user.toJson());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return response.data.value;
    } else {
      final error =
          response.data.errors[0] ?? "Error";
      throw Exception(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: The status code 400 is handled in your backend ?

Comment: yes. i already figured out how to handle. but if you know a better way please let me know. thank you ! @dm_tr

Comment: Yes your method ain't bad despite you can avoid intercepting the error twice

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to put on DioError in the catch block of the code. This way i'll be able to manage and access the custom error coming from the backend.

```
try {
      final response =
          await api.dio.post('api/users/buyer', data: user.toJson());
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        return response.data.value;
      } else {
        final error =
            response.data.errors[0] ?? "Error";
        throw Exception(error);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is DioError) {
        //This is the custom message coming from the backend
        throw e.response.data['errors'][0] ??
            "Error";
      } else {
        throw Exception("Error");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling Dio exceptions like a PRO

// dio call

```
            Future<Customer> getProfileData() async {
              Dio dio = Dio();
              var options = BaseOptions(baseUrl: "YOUR_BASE_URL", headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              });
              dio.options = options;
            
              try {
     
               var response = await dio.get("YOUR_END_POINTS");
                return Customer.fromJson(response.data);
              } on DioError catch (e) {
                 throw  DioExceptions.fromDioError(dioError: e, errorFrom: "getProfileData").errorMessage();
             // if you want to customize the error message
            //  int statusCode =  DioExceptions.fromDioError(dioError: e, errorFrom: "getProfileData").errorStatusCode();
            //  if(statusCode == 404)
            //  {
            //    throw "Incorrect Email Password";
            //  }
              }
            }
```

/// EXCEPTION HANDLER

```
                      import 'dart:convert';
                  import 'dart:developer';
                  
                  import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
                  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
                  
                  class DioExceptions implements Exception {
                    static late String message;
                    static int statusCode = -1;
                  
                    DioExceptions.fromDioError(
                        {required DioError dioError, required String? errorFrom}) {
                      //This will print error is Json format and colorful
                      _prettyPrintError(dioError: dioError, errorFrom: errorFrom);
                      switch (dioError.type) {
                        case DioErrorType.cancel:
                          message = "Request to API server was cancelled";
                          break;
                        case DioErrorType.connectTimeout:
                          message = "Connection timeout with API server";
                          break;
                        case DioErrorType.receiveTimeout:
                          message = "Receive timeout in connection with API server";
                          break;
                        case DioErrorType.response:
                          message = _handleError(
                            dioError.response?.statusCode,
                            dioError.response?.data,
                          );
                          statusCode = dioError.response?.statusCode ?? -1;
                          break;
                        case DioErrorType.sendTimeout:
                          message = "Send timeout in connection with API server";
                          break;
                        case DioErrorType.other:
                          if (dioError.message.contains("SocketException")) {
                            message = 'No Internet';
                            break;
                          }
                          message = "Unexpected error occurred";
                          break;
                        default:
                          message = "Something went wrong";
                          break;
                      }
                    }
                  
                    String _handleError(int? statusCode, dynamic error) {
                      switch (statusCode) {
                        case 400:
                          return 'Bad request';
                        case 401:
                          return 'Unauthorized';
                        case 403:
                          return 'Forbidden';
                        case 404:
                          return error['message'];
                        case 500:
                          return 'Internal server error';
                        case 502:
                          return 'Bad gateway';
                        default:
                          return 'Oops something went wrong';
                      }
                    }
                  
                    String errorMessage() => message;
                  
                    int errorStatusCode() => statusCode;
                  
                    void _prettyPrintError(
                        {required DioError dioError, required String? errorFrom}) {
                      debugPrint(
                          '\x1B[31m${"********************************************************"}\x1B[0m');
                      debugPrint('\x1B[31m${" ERROR exception from: $errorFrom"}\x1B[0m');
                      debugPrint(
                          '\x1B[31m${" ERROR it's status Code : ${dioError.response?.statusCode ?? -1}"}\x1B[0m');
                      try {
                        JsonEncoder encoder = const JsonEncoder.withIndent('  ');
                        String prettyprint = encoder.convert(dioError.response?.data ?? '');
                        debugPrint(
                            '\x1B[31m${"********************************************************"}\x1B[0m');
                        log("️$errorFrom Error Response :\n$prettyprint", name: "Error");
                        debugPrint(
                            '\x1B[31m️$errorFrom Error Response :\n$prettyprint", name: "Error"\x1B[0m');
                        debugPrint(
                            '\x1B[31m${"********************************************************"}\x1B[0m');
                      } catch (e) {
                        log("️ $errorFrom Error Response :\n${dioError.response?.data ?? ''}",
                            name: "Error");
                        debugPrint(
                            '\x1B[31m${"********************************************************"}\x1B[0m');
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

**And on Console you have coloured json**
[image]